# How do i have a state as a variable for a graqh ql query (Apollo)

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

So what I'm trying to do is have a state as a variable for my query to retrieve data from graphQl.The problem I'm facing is that since it doesn't read the component state from there.

How do I go about this?

```
class usersScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var white = 'sdfss';
    console.log(props)
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
    this.state = {
        active : true,
        clientId: "5acc83c4658e6c2c70b3fe1d"
    };
  };

 }
 export default graphql(GET_CLIENT_USERS, {
    options:(state) => (console.log(state),{
    variables:{
        clientId:this.state.clientId}})
 })(usersScreen);
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe use the new [QueryComponent](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#basic). You can then use the state in the components render method easily.

Comment: On react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `refetch` in your component to pass variables in `componentDidMount` for example instead of passing them as options:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.data.refetch({clientId:this.state.clientId})
 }
```

Another option to move the render logic to a new component `ConnectecUsersScreen` and in the render of `usersScreen` you can pass the state as a porp:

```
render() {
    <ConnectecUsersScreen clientId={this.state.clientId} />
  }
```

Now you can pass `ConnectecUsersScreen` to `graphql` and you will have access to `clientId` as props.

Comment: I'm getting a "ReferenceError: clientId is not defined"

Comment: You are passing clientId instead of props.clientId as variables and that’s where you got the referenceError from. Anyway, you no longer need to pass options anymore. Remove the second argument of ‘graphql’. You don’t need to pass any variables since you are using refetch now.

Comment: I spoke too soon, it stopped working, is it possible to restructure the code for me, maybe I'm not doing it correctly. 
 here https://jsfiddle.net/7b757ymd/

Comment: I can definitely take a look if you just clean your code a bit and remove snippets not related to your original question.

Comment: I still can't run your code. Try to add this and let me know if it works: 
`export default graphql(GET_CLIENT_USERS, {
  options: () => ({variables: {clientId: ""}})
})(usersScreen);`

Comment: Its cool bro, thank you, I used the second method. but with a screenProps

Answer (score 0):

Used screen Props to pass the `clientId` to all the screens under my stack navigation.

```
render() {
  <ConnectecUsersScreen screenProps={clientId:this.state.clientId} />
 }
```